# JavaScript date-time max/min not working when the user types in values manually

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I'm currently using the JavaScript built in date-time. The max/min constraints, however, seem to only apply when the user uses the graphical arrows to change the values. For example, if I change the day in this code using the arrows, and try to increase the day past `06-14`, it will automatically reset to `06-07`. However, if I set the day manually using my keyboard, I can set it to any number, disregarding the max/min (i.e. I can set the date to `06-01` if I type in 1). Is there any way to fix this?

```html
    <label for="meeting-time">Choose a time for your appointment: </label>

    <input type="datetime-local" id="meeting-time"
       name="meeting-time" value="2018-06-12T19:30"
       min="2018-06-07T00:00" max="2018-06-14T00:00">
```

Comment: seems that will be validate when user submits the values as a part of form

Answer (score 4):

All html5 validation works with form on submit. If you want to validate by own, apply on submit callback function. using `novalidate` attribute in form

```html
 <form action="#">
    <label for="meeting-time">Choose a time for your appointment: </label>

    <input type="datetime-local" id="meeting-time"
       name="meeting-time" value="2018-06-12T19:30"
       min="2018-06-07T00:00" max="2018-06-14T00:00">
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: thank you! It works. If I wanted to validate by own in addition to the normal validation (i.e. I want to check min/max AND check if the day is not a Saturday or Sunday), would I omit the novalidate? And what should my submit callback function return, a boolean?

Comment: you can learn here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Answer (score -1):

You will need to convert the manual input to a js Datetime object first.

```
const yourDate = new Date(*userinput*);
```